# I am given two points $A$ and $B$, find a point three times as far from point $A$ as point$ B$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am given two points : $A(2,4,-8)$ and $ B(0,-2,-6)$.
I am supposed to find a point three times as far from point $A$ as point $B$.
How am I supposed to approach this problem?

Comment: Vectors could be useful... Consider the vector $\vec{AB}$

Comment: Or maybe you should consider using the formula for the distance between two points.

Comment: Did OP already delete his/her profile?

Comment: A Cartesian oval

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do it is to extend the line segment $AB$ by a factor of $3$ to get a new endpoint $C(x, y, z)$. To do this, use similar triangles to observe that:
$$
3 = \frac{x - 2}{0 - 2} = \frac{y - 4}{-2 - 4} = \frac{z - (-8)}{-6 - (-8)}
$$
Set each fraction equal to the scale factor $3$ to solve for the new point's coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

There is such a point on the interval $AB$. It is located $1/4$ of the interval length from $B$ and $3/4$ of the interval length from $A$. The coordinates of the point are easily found to be: $(0.5, -0.5, -6.5)$.